# JavaScript pre set function parameter

Tags: javascript, partial-application

I have a series of events I'm listening to (not DOM ones), and an object containing event handler functions.

Typically I'd do something like

`whenEventOccurs('event-name', handler.eventName)`

Except that I have to pass a parameter to the handler that changes for every event listener.

I am looking for something like `Function.prototype.bind()` that doesn't set `this` but sets the first parameter, if possible.

If there is no clean solution, I can always do the following, but I'd like to avoid it if possible:

```
whenEventOccurs('event-name', function(foo, bar, baz){
    handler.eventName(specialParam, foo, bar, baz);
});
```

Comment: You can return a function with necessary bindings

Answer (score 2):

You can encapsulate it in a function that works similarly to `bind()`

```
function bindArg1(func, arg1) {
    return function() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        args.unshift(arg1);
        return func.apply(this, args);
    }
}

whenEventOccurs('event-name', bindArg1(handler.eventName, specialParam))
```

Comment: How would I pass parameters other than the special parameter?

Comment: Also, the `this` scope is then impossible to use, meaning I can't reference other things in `handler`

Comment: If you're going to pass other parameters, just use the code you wrote in the question.

Comment: `bind1Arg` passes on `this` in the `.apply()` call.

Comment: See the duplicate question for how to bind an arbitrary number of arguments, not just the first argument.

Comment: Unless bindArg1 is part of `handler` it passes the wrong scope

Comment: When you do `whenEventOccurs('event-name', handler.eventName)`, the scope isn't `handler`, it's whatever `whenEventOccurs` sets as the scope when it calls the callback. When you use `bindArg1`, the same thing happens.

Comment: You can write `bindArg1(handler.eventName.bind(handler), specialParam)`